# primefaces update table row after cell edit

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using primefaces datatbale cell editing , when I edit the   a cell the next column of that row should display a calculated value which is calculated from this cell value,I am using  celleditEvent to invoke a listener   using

Please advice in my listener is there a way to retrieve the  id of the tr and add to request context to update this row. Please advice.

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent  cellEditEvent){

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(((DataTable)cellEditEvent.getSource()).getClientId());
}
```

in this event method it it possible to retrieve html id of the tr element containing this cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OmniFaces with PrimeFaces

Take a look at this : http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Ajax